# ubnldr.mbr is missing dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, unetbootin

As I don't have access to a usb or CD, I have tried to frugal install ubuntu onto my HDD, using Unetbootin. Once turning on I find the dual boot menu to select the OS, and attempt to boot Ubuntu, with no avail. An error appears saying

> Windows failed to start.A recent hardware or software problem might be
>   the case.

It then says File:

> ubnldr.mbr status: 0xc00007B.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is either a bug or incompatibility in Unetbootin. Rather than try and fix it, it would be easier to buy or borrow a USB flash or CD drive and use that to install. Or, if you really want an install in Windows, use VirtualBox.